# List of objects within Class definition

Tags: c#, class

I'm in process of learning C# and have a question about behavior and best practice in a particular instance. I'm creating a class as below:

```
public class DecryptObj
{
    private string key;
    private int numMatches;
    private string decryptStr;

    private static List<DecryptObj> _decryptList = new List<DecryptObj>();

....
}
```

So I've got a class that has 3 fields and a list of objects of that class. My assumption is that by declaring the list as static that there is only one instance of this list. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.) My question is if it would be better (best practice) to declare a second class that is the list instead. Please feel free to comment on other things stylistically as I'd like to learn what others do.

Thanks!

Comment: Would the class just be this list? This seems like the best way to do it - mainly because the list is private to the DecryptObj class this way. Plus who likes looking through hundreds of tiny classes or a giant static class? Anyway this is question is probably a bit too subjective.

Comment: if you want to create a Class which has only a `Single Instance` then read up about `Singleton`otherwise you would want to create like you are private static List<T>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you need only 1 list of that class, this is the proper way to do this. If you multiple list of that class, maybe it's better to declare another class for it

Comment: One list it is. Thanks!